# Port forwarding in android

Tags: internet, ssh, remote-access

I have a **rooted** android device in which I have installed SSH server. i need to access my device outside my LANi.e. over the **internet**.inorder to access it over the internet i need to enable port forwarding . so , is there any way of forwarding ports in android?

Comment: What's the network scenario here? If your Android device is under a local network, be it wired/wireless, and the device has to be accessed from a system outside this network then you would need to forward ports at the router/switch -- off-topic here. If the device is simply connected to Internet (using mobile data) and has a public IP address, then you should be able to access the server without any port-forwarding.

Comment: I meant i can access it in my LAN . But i cant access it via my public IP